# Returning a dictionary with keys as words and the values as two-element lists

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-operator

Returning a dictionary whose keys are words and whose values are two-element lists [spam_count,non_spam_count] corresponding to how many times we saw that in both spam and nonspam messages. I am not able to understand the following from the below code. Any help will be much appreciated!
What is this statement doing and the concept behind it: `counts[word][0 if is_spam else 1 ]+=1`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_words(training_set):
    """TRAINING SET CONSISTS OF PAIRS (message,is_spam)"""
    counts=defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])
    for message,is_spam in training_set:
        for word in tokenize(message):
            counts[word][0 if is_spam else 1 ]+=1
    return counts

x=[('rain is great','data'),('morning','data'),
   ('lazy','creditcard'),('enjoy','mumbai')]
count_words(x)

import re

def tokenize(message):
    message=message.lower()
    all_words=re.split("\W+",message)
    return set(all_words)
```

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: @SL5net It is in Python

Comment: The second element of the tuples in x is supposed to be bool, isn't it?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins is_spam contains a particular word that is considered to be a spam for example the word 'creditcard' is a spam and is contained in the message that we have to check is a spam or not.

Comment: When you write `if is_spam` you imply that `is_spam` is bool. If it is a string it will always evaluate to `True` unless the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

- `counts` -> that's your dictionary of words to tuples
- `counts[word]` -> that's a tuple of the form `[spam_count, non_spam_count]`

Now, to access the components of this tuple, you can do:

```py
spam_count, non_spam_count = counts[word]
```

But you can also do:

```py
spam_count = counts[word][0]
non_spam_count = counts[word][1]
```

- `0 if is_spam else 1` -> this evaluates to `0` if `is_spam` is True and to `1` otherwise
- `counts[word][0 if is_spam else 1]` -> if `is_spam` is true then this is the first element of the tuple, i.e. `spam_count`. Otherwise this is the second element of the tuple.
- `counts[word][0 if is_spam else 1] += 1` -> this increments `spam_count` if `is_spam` is True and otherwise increments `non_spam_count`.

Hopefully, this is enough of a walkthrough for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is [ternary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), same as

```
if is_spam:
    counts[word][0] += 1
else:
    counts[word][1] += 1
```